# Opening Multiple instances of the same view in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, view, multiple-instances

So im relativley new to this view/perspective development and have come across a problem. My views only open once and another instance cannot be opened again even when I load different data.

Ive looked everywhere and all i can find people saying is that I need a secondary id etc... but no explaination of where to go to do this or how to go about this.

I need instances of my views to be opend multiple times if possible all with different data. these views are opened and controlled through a tree view i have created.

These views are currently just an extension of the Java perspective in eclipse 4.5.2.

Any pointers in the right direction would be a great help!

Comment: When you open the view, using, e.g., `getActivePage().showView(...)` you pass a secondary ID. This 2nd id can be any non-empty `String`. If you will need to find the view again, use something sensible. See [the javadocs for showView](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIWorkbenchWindow.html). See also [How to create multiple instances of one ViewPart](https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/168-eclipse/1572-how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-one-viewpart.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the secondary id for the view when you show it using `IWorkbenchPage.showView`:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.showView("view id", "secondary id", IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

`"secondary id"` must be different for each instance of the view.

Comment: Thanks man ! just specifying where i needed to put it was enough for me to work out exactly what i needed to do

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use two windows connected to same workspace instant. When you are debugging and is paused at a debug point, choose: **Window -> New Window**. Then another window gets opened. Let the new and old windows be side by side. Now for example, in this newly opened window, choose: **Window -> Show View -> Debug**. Now you will get the same line of code opened at which the debug is paused in the old window. Now choose: **Window -> Show View -> Variables**. Now you get two Variable views which have the same instances of variables available. In my case, I wanted to compare old and new values present in one complicated object and it was easy when I could compare them side by side, rather than scrolling up and down in Variables view.